# How I convert "2020-09-23T15:08:03.259Z" into time format in data studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm facing trouble to convert "2020-09-23T15:08:03.259Z" into basic time format in google data studio. Can anyone please help me to figure out this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `PARSE_DATETIME` in a custom field:

`PARSE_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ", DateTimeText)`, where DateTimeText is your original field with the date time string.

- [Docs](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739558) on `PARSE_DATETIME`.
- [Format elements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#supported_format_elements_for_datetime) list.